# how to use libtar in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

i want to untar a file in iphone.how can i do it?libtar is available, but how can i integrate with iphone SDK?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://pseudogreen.org/blog/build_autoconfed_libs_for_iphone.html) a good post with a [script](http://pseudogreen.org/bzr/sandbox/iphone/build_for_iphoneos) to compile and install a library to Iphone.

If you have the possibility, switch to zip as well said in this [post](http://blog.hawkey.org/?p=332).

Comment: The URL says to run the script in the directory that contains your package's configure script,what that directory means?have you experienced this to execute the script?

Comment: after installing script, how can i add libtar  folder into project file, any help pls?

Comment: Copy the script in libtar sources package, configure it and launch it.

Comment: please fix links